# Why I cannot save the new form to database?

Tags: django, django-forms

I really don't know what's the problem of my code.I'm using django connected to my database, and try to save my new data into database, here is the models.py:

```
class guest_room(models.Model):
    room_number=models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True)
    room_type=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    room_status=models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Here is the form.py:

```
class guest_room_form(forms.ModelForm):  
class Meta:  
    model = guest_room  
    fields = ['room_number', 'room_type', 'room_status'] 
    widgets = { 'room_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }), 
        'room_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
        'room_status': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
  }
```

Here is the views.py:

```
def addnewroom(request):
    if request.method=="post":
        form=guest_room_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("guestroom")

    else:
        form=guest_room_form()
    return render(request,'addnewroom.html',{'form':form})
```

This is my html of the add new data page:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="../addnewroom/">     {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Enter Details</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Room Number:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">      {{ form.room_number }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">      {{ form.room_type }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee Contact:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">      {{ form.room_status }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to go back to the 'guestroom.html' after submitting successfully, but now after I submit, it stayed at the same page. I cannot find the new form in database too. What goes wrong??

Comment: The method is in uppercase, so `request.method == 'POST'`, regardless how you specify it in the form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OMG I really got stuck at here for a long time. It works! Thank you so much : ) And thank you for answering so in time!